# Assigning class that inherits from a constrained generic base class to the inherited base class with the constrained generic

Tags: c#, class, oop, generics, inheritance

I have a base class:

```
public abstract class Foo<T> where T : TBase { ... }
```

I also have the following classes that implement TBase:

```
public abstract class ImplementsTBase1 : TBase { ... }
public abstract class ImplementsTBase2 : TBase { ... }
```

I create new classes that implement this:

```
public class Bar1 : Foo<ImplementsTBase1> { ... }
public class Bar2 : Foo<ImplementsTBase2> { ... }
```

Now I want to add two instances of these classes to a container like so:

```
public static List<Foo<TBase>> FooList = new List<Foo<TBase>>();
...
FooList.Add(new Bar1());
FooList.Add(new Bar2());
```

However, I cannot do this. What can I do to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define an interface that defines `T` as [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)

> An interface that has a contravariant type parameter allows its methods to accept arguments of less derived types than those specified by the interface type parameter.

```
public interface IFoo<out T> where T : TBase{}
```

then derive from it:

```
public abstract class Foo<T> : IFoo<T> where T : TBase{}
```

now you can

```
List<IFoo<TBase>> FooList = new List<IFoo<TBase>>();
```

and

```
FooList.Add(new Bar1());
FooList.Add(new Bar2());
```

works nicely.

Of course, this will place constraints on the methods that `IFoo<out T>` can implement.